# What is acceptable in a python try statement

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a try statement that roughly follows something like this.

```
for result in results['matches']:
    try:
        #runs some functions
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        leaveopt = raw_input( 'Would you like to exit or skip the current match? [e/s]:' )
        if leaveopt == 'e':
            print '\nExiting...'
        else:
            print '\nSkipping match...'
```

When I run the program I get no errors but when I press ctrl-c it just skips the current match rather than asking what I would like to do. I'm wondering if there is only some content that can be ran in the except portion of a try statement or if there is another problem.

Comment: Do any of your functions inside the `try` have catch blocks? They may be blindingly catching any exceptions..

Comment: None have catch blocks. the majority just print to a file and the others just run nmap

Comment: I tried running your code using an infinite loop and a `print` statement inside the `try` (http://pastebin.com/UDNBBYLG), it works as expected. I think the problem is in something you've left out.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. One of the functions ran a system command that took a while to complete so when CTRL-c is pressed it kills the program and moves on rather than being recognized by python.

Answer (score 1):

There's no restriction on what you can do in an `except` as far as I know (even if there are some things that you may want to avoid here), and this works for me (python 2.7.3 / linux mint):

```
import time

for x in xrange(5000):
    try:
        print x
        time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        leaveopt = raw_input( 
            'Would you like to exit or skip the current match? [e/s]:'
            )
        if leaveopt == 'e':
            print '\nExiting...'
            break
        else:
            print '\nSkipping match...'
            continue
```

The problem is obviously somewhere in the "run some functions" part.